# Nodejs Expressjs Cluster Proper way to cluster app.js

Tags: node.js, express, web, cluster-computing

Does anyone know which is the correct way to cluster a nodejs express application and why?

Option A: The app instance is created once and the listen is called on each fork that is created.

```
        var app = require('express')();

        if (cluster.isMaster) {
        //fork once per cpu
        for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
            cluster.fork();
        }

        //if a worker is online
        cluster.on('online', function WorkerOnline(worker) {
            console.log('%s Worker is running on %s pid: ', new Date().toISOString(), worker.process.pid);
        });
        //if a worker dies, log that and create a new one
        cluster.on('exit', function workerDed(worker, code, signal) {
            cluster.fork();
        });
    } else {
        //non-master forks listen on the ip/port specified in the config
        app.listen(config, function () {
            console.log('%s Express server listening on ip %s:%s ', new Date().toISOString(), config.ip, config.port);
        });
    }
```

Option B: The app is created and listen is called every time there is a fork.

```
     if (cluster.isMaster) {
        //fork once per cpu
        for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
            cluster.fork();
        }

        //if a worker is online
        cluster.on('online', function workeronline(worker) {
            console.log('%s Worker is running on %s pid: ', new Date().toISOString(), worker.process.pid);
        });
        //if a worker dies, log that and create a new one
        cluster.on('exit', function workeronline(worker, code, signal) {
            cluster.fork();
        });
    } else {
        //non-master forks listen on the ip/port specified in the config
        var app = require('express')();

        app.listen(8000, function() {
        console.log('Process ' + process.pid + ' is listening to all incoming requests');});
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is fine. When Node.js calls `cluster.fork()`, it runs a new Node instance and calls your app.js file all over again. Therefore, the line `var app = express();` can be called anywhere and you can guarantee that it will be different from the Express object as instantiated on other instances (i.e. your master and slave processes do not share the `app` variable).

However, Option B makes it clearer that you are creating a new Express instance every time you fork. In addition, in Option A, you create an Express object on the master *and* slave processes, but the master process does not use the Express object you created.

Note this block:

```
} else {
    app.listen(config, function () {
        console.log('%s Express server listening on ip %s:%s ',
        new Date().toISOString(), config.ip, config.port);
    });
}
```

You only make the Express object listen on a port iff it's a child process; calling `var app = express();` outside of the `else` block in Option A is pointless as you create an Express object but it is not used in the master process. This draws into question why you would want to use Option A at all.

Comment: All the setup of the app object can make the else case start to look kludgy and confusing. otherwise I agree. My approach going forward would be to separate the construction of the app and export the listen or equivalent so that the cluster logic can be further separated into a cluster.js file. I would then launch node cluster.js which will then launch my app in the else but the construction and listen will be encapsulated in the app.js. This will allow me to launch in production clustered but locally I can launch app.js directly fo debug etc. if I want. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, and I agree it is good to do so for development, as having all of your imports and setup in one else statement is ugly :)